Unable to build wt_4.10.4 on macos hitting error on Wt::AsioWrapper::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query
Hitting error when building Wt_4.10.4 on macos.
build steps:
%> cd <wt/download/directory>
%> mkdir build
%> cd build
%> cmake ../
%> make -j8

Fillowing the standard build process described in Wt git project:
https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/InstallationUnix.html
/Users/thomaspeters/Development/C-Projects/wt-4.10.4/src/http/Server.C:334:11: error: object of type 'asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query' (aka 'basic_resolver_query<boost::asio::ip::tcp>') cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
  334 |     query = Wt::AsioWrapper::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(Wt::AsioWrapper::asio::ip::tcp::v6(), address, "http");
      |           ^
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/ip/basic_resolver_query.hpp:225:3: note: copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted because 'basic_resolver_query<boost::asio::ip::tcp>' has a user-declared move constructor
  225 |   basic_resolver_query(basic_resolver_query&& other)
      |   ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [src/http/CMakeFiles/wthttp.dir/Server.C.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/http/CMakeFiles/wthttp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Boost Version:
10-85-00

I successfully built and installed Boost using ./bootstrap and ./b2 install.
Macos version:
ProductName:        macOS
Product Version:     15.0
BuildVersion:       24A5298h

Processor:
2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9

Wt version:
wt-4.10.4


There is a few simple steps to fix it:

You have to open Server.C
Go to 334 row and replace
query = ...
to
auto new_query = ....
then you need to change all "query" to "new_query"


not clear...  thanks for trying.

I am waiting for the next release 4.11.0 which has been promised from the vendor.
